# Call a model method in a Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, controller, instantiation

I'm have some difficulties here, I am unable to successfully call a method which belongs to a `ProjectPage` *model* in the `ProjectPage` *controller*.

I have in my `ProjectPage` controller:

```
def index
  @searches = Project.published.financed     
  @project_pages = form_search(params)
end
```

And in my `ProjectPage` *model*:

```
def form_search(searches)
  searches = searches.where('amount > ?', params[:price_min]) if check_params(params[:price_min])
  @project_pages = ProjectPage.where(:project_id => searches.pluck(:'projects.id'))
end
```

However, I am unable to successfully call the `form_search` *method*.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

To complete davidb's answer, two things you're doing wrong are:

1) you're calling a model's function from a controller, when the model function is only defined in the model itself. So you do need to call

```
Project.form_search
```

and define the function with

```
def self.form_search
```

2) you're calling params from the model. In the MVC architecture, the model doesn't know anything about the request, so params is not defined there. Instead, you'll need to pass the variable to your function like you're already doing...

Comment: Thanks the `self` is what i was missing

Answer (score 22):

Three  thing:

1.) When you want to create a class wide method thats not limited to an object of the class you need to define it like

```
def self.method_name
  ..
end
```

and not

```
def method_name
  ...
end
```

2.) This can be done using a `scope` with `lambda` these are really nice features. Like This in the model add:

```
scope :form_search, lambda{|q| where("amount > ?", q) }
```

Will enable you to call

```
Project.form_search(params[:price_min])
```

The secound step would be to add a scope to the `ProjectPage` model so everything is at the place it belongs to!

3.) When you call a Class method in the Controller you need to specifiy the Model like this:

```
Class.class_method
```

Answer (score 4):

Declare like this in model

```
def self.form_search(searches)
  searches = searches.where('amount > ?', params[:price_min]) if check_params(params[:price_min])
  @project_pages = ProjectPage.where(:project_id => searches.pluck(:'projects.id'))
end
```

and call from controller

```
@project_pages = ProjectPage.form_search(params)
```